# What is a more efficient way of structuring this Rails quiz model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

They say that a rails paradigm is to not repeat yourself, or "DRY". So I'm working on this quiz app, and now that I've slowly understood how MVC works somewhat and how it's all coming together, I want to write better code. So let's take this example that I did earlier from my schema:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_id"
    t.text "answer_choice"
    t.text "answer_choice_2"
    t.text "answer_choice_3"
    t.text "answer_choice_4"
    t.text "answer_choice_5"
    t.text "correct_answer_choice"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

As you can see, answer_choice, then adding _2, _3, _4, _5 and correct_answer_choice seem very ugly and inefficient to me. What if I want to add a post that only has two answer choices? Or three? Maybe more?

What would be a better way of going about this so it's more adaptable and flexible?

Comment: If this is working code, this question might be better asked on CodeReviewSE, provided it meets the rest of the criteria for asking a question (which I am not familiar with).

Comment: Put all the answers in one `JSON` column called `answers`

Comment: @NickM, but I'm not using JSON in my rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler with just a `given_answer`, and `correct_answer` columns in your table per post. For your `given_answer` column, you can use `options_for_select` to display the choices in your form:

```
options_for_select([ "Choice1", "Choice2", etc... ])
```

After submission, you can then query `if correct_answer == given_answer` to see if the two values match up.